# trouble with inputenc package

Tags: input-encodings

im having a hard time with TeXnicCenter 2.0 (with MikTex) on Windows 7. I set up a quite simple code. But the letters äüö seem to appear when they want to. 
I got a project file with another file bounded with `\input`. In both files I wrote some ö or ä to chek which package can deal with it. But apparently nither one can. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} 

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   

%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\input{LaTeX1}

test ö


\end{document}
```

in the file LaTeX1.tex I just wrote `text ä`

So if i use:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  -> no errors, but "test ö" is not shown
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   ->  one error. no "ä" is not shown. "test ö" is shown correctly
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} -> no errors. "text ä" is shown, "test ö": shown with stange signs
```

Im a LaTex beginner so please dont answer to complicated :)

Thanks for your answers!

Vicky

Comment: It's important to know what encoding you've actually saved the two files in: they might not be the same as each other!

Comment: Change the encoding of LaTeX1.tex to utf8. Then use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. You could also use `{\inputencoding{ansinew}\input{LaTeX1}}` to change the settings locally. But mixing encodings in one project can get confusing so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What happens if you replace `\input{LaTeX1}` with `text ä`? Then you'd just be reducing the problem down to a single file, rather than two.

Comment: Ok! Now, how can I change the encoding of LaTeX1.tex to utf8? And how can I see which encoding is used in the file?

Comment: to John Wickerson: if the code works I wont to start a big project with several files included with \input. So the text ä stands for a hole document with a lot of text and many ä ü ö's :) but good idea anyway

Comment: I don't know if texniccenter can reencode files. But you can always create a new file (normally this should be utf8) and copy the content from the old file to this one. And for the encoding test: If with `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` the umlauts are ok then the file is utf8.

Comment: I use Notepad++ for writing my LaTeX-files. You can use it to switch the encoding very easily (convert to UTF-8 without bom). But a lot of editors have that feature.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you post this as an answer please, so the question can be concluded.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).